# What is the best way to parse a URL with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url, jquery.address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168260/how-to-parse-a-url)

I'm using the [jQuery address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) and I want to know what the preferred method is for parsing URLs in JavaScript. Should I use a regex for each URL, or is there a better way?

As an example, one of my urls looks like this from my address change event:

```
/visits=10
```

My existing address change event simply displays the URL that was changed.

```
// Handle handle change events
$.address.change(function(e) {
    alert(e.value);
    // Call the correct page based on the page number
});
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Check jquery url plugin: http://ajaxcssblog.com/jquery/url-read-request-variables/