# How to get url path without $_GET parameters using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

If my current page is in this format...

```
http://www.mydomain.com/folder/mypage.php?param=value
```

Is there an easy way to get this

```
http://www.mydomain.com/folder/mypage.php
```

using javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do this regex and splitting stuff. Use the browser's built-in URL parser.

```
window.location.origin + window.location.pathname
```

And if you need to parse a URL that isn't the current page:

```
var url = document.createElement('a');
url.href = "http://www.example.com/some/path?name=value#anchor";
console.log(url.origin + url.pathname);
```

And to support IE (because IE doesn't have `location.origin`):

```
location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname;
```

(Inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6168370/711902)

Comment: I have to agree, this accomplishes exactly what I needed without any unnecessary steps. Thank you.

Comment: this doesn't work in Opera 12 (and earlier) and in IE (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_origin.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `split` like

```
var url = "http://www.mydomain.com/folder/mypage.php?param=value";
var url_array = url.split("?");
alert(url_array[0]);    //Alerts http://www.mydomain.com/folder/mypage.php
```

Even we have many parameters in the `GET` , **the first segment** will be the `URL` without `GET` parameters.

This is [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1471/)

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed! I did not mention it in the question, but this also works when no parameters are passed =)

Comment: How would your string-based solution handle a malformed URL, such as `http://www.domain.com/page#anchor?parameter` ? Using the document object and it's api is a more robust solution IMO

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
var url=document.location.href;
var mainurl=url.split("?");
alert(mainurl[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var result = yourUrl.substring(0, yourUrl.indexOf('?'));
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1468/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.slice(1))
     .split('&')
     .reduce(function _reduce (/*Object*/ a, /*String*/ b) {
     b = b.split('=');
     a[b[0]] = b[1];
     return a;
   }, {});
```