# Get Value from url with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a symphony built, in which I have a page working with Angularjs 1.5.*.

I'm not using the angularjs route so I don't have the variables there.

My url is (and might change where the 16 is, though always at the end of url):

> www.mydomain.com/billing/detail/16

I want to get the 16 from the url.

Just want to get that number and handle it in my controller so I can call a symphony controller and get the data I currently have hardcoded.

Thanks !!!!

Comment: will the url always be "www.mydomain.com/billing/detail/??"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168260/how-to-parse-a-url)

Comment: Yes. It's going to be like that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window.location object.

```
location.pathname.split("/").pop()
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the work. I was trying to use angular and wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use $routeParams, you could try to get the url using

```
$location.absUrl();
```

and then parse it to get the value you need.

Answer (score 0):

you should use $stateParams.
like `$somevar = $stateParams.urlParamName;`

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the Url into a string using like below:

```
var url = new URI('www.mydomain.com/billing/detail/16'); 

url.path(); which will return '/billing/detail/
```

Then you can just use split like this:

```
var url = "www.mydomain.com/billing/detail/16";

$scope.myvalue = getUrlID(url);

function getUrlID(str) {
    return str.split('www.mydomain.com/billing/detail/')[1];
}
```

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PYW9QzqsmOL12VzNkwWo?p=preview).  Of course it is hardcoded in the plunker because I can't access your URL, but this should get you going.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. Found the solution with javascript.

Comment: No problem.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$location.absUrl().split("/").pop()
```

Comment: Should have been a comment! If you don't have enough score to add comments, add more details to support your answer. Flagged in [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16555520)