# Best way to split URL into array in clean way?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract the directory and file name in a different input of user URL's.

Some examples would include:

- https://foo/s3.amazonaws.com/TOP_PROD_IMAGE/WS-25612-BK_IMRO_1.jpg
- http://192.168.12.44:8090/TOP_PROD_IMAGE/R3CRDT-HZWT_IMRO_1.jpg
- www.foobar-images.s3.amazonaws.com/TOP_PROD_IMAGE/WS-25612-BK_IMRO_1.jpg

What I **really** need is the `TOP_PROD_IMAGE` and `WS-25612-BK_IMRO_1.jpg` file name.

So I would need to account for users who enter `http://` or `https://` or just `www`. so I tried using `string.split('/')` but that obviously wouldn't work in all cases. Is there something that could give me an array despite the double `//` in cases where user enters http? Thanks!

Comment: I'd use path-to-regexp for this.  it's used within Express internally, and can be quite robust.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp  If this really is just a one-off use case though, you could do it directly with regex.

Comment: `([^/]+)\/([^/]+)$` as a regexp?

Comment: This question reminded me of a similar one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45075028/4003419) But this one should be a lot easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider:

```js
const [file, folder] = url.split('/').reverse();
```

With this you wouldn't need to consider `http://` or any `//`

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
const url = new URL('https://foo/s3.amazonaws.com/TOP_PROD_IMAGE/WS-25612-BK_IMRO_1.jpg')
const urlParams = url.pathname.split('/') // you'll get array here, so inspect it and get last two items
```

Will this do the trick? You'll get exactly what you need within the `pathname`.

Comment: Also handled query parameters gracefully

Comment: Wow, this is super nice! Also anyway to isolate file name? I guess I could work with `URL.pathname` would just be nicer to have them separate.

Comment: The answer below will get you there. Answer from @C_Ogoo.

Answer (score 0):

If the urls have to start with either `http` and optional `s` or `www.` you could also use a pattern with 2 capturing groups to get the part before the last slash and the part after the last slash.

```
^(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S+\/([^/]+)\/(\S+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JU7Ss3/1)

```js
urls = [
  "https://foo/s3.amazonaws.com/TOP_PROD_IMAGE/WS-25612-BK_IMRO_1.jpg",
  "http://192.168.12.44:8090/TOP_PROD_IMAGE/R3CRDT-HZWT_IMRO_1.jpg",
  "www.foobar-images.s3.amazonaws.com/TOP_PROD_IMAGE/WS-25612-BK_IMRO_1.jpg"
].forEach(s => {
  let m = s.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S+\/([^/]+)\/(\S+)$/, s);
  console.log(m[1]);
  console.log(m[2]);
  console.log("\n");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative look-aheads to only match the final URI segments:

`/(?!([https?:\/\/]|[www.]))(?!([\d]))(?!(.*[com])).*/`

```js
const re = /(?!([https?:\/\/]|[www.]))(?!([\d]))(?!(.*[com])).*/
const arr = [
  "https://foo/s3.amazonaws.com/TOP_PROD_IMAGE/WS-25612-BK_IMRO_1.jpg",
  "http://192.168.12.44:8090/TOP_PROD_IMAGE/R3CRDT-HZWT_IMRO_1.jpg",
  "www.foobar-images.s3.amazonaws.com/TOP_PROD_IMAGE/WS-25612-BK_IMRO_1.jpg"
]

const res = arr.map(str => re.exec(str)[0].split("/"))

console.log(res)
```