# Send post id from URL to Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

how can i send the post id on this URL inside my id variable, i needed for an ajax function
This is the URL

https://barrera.pe/prueba/productos/barrera-3/?id=204

```
$(document).on('click','.more-link',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        id   = link.attr('href').replace(/^.*?id=/,''); 
        
        $.ajax({...
        ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168260/how-to-parse-a-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use new [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) function and use [searchparams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) with `get` to extract `id` from your `href` which will be in the `a` element and pass it your `ajax` request.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.more-link', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var url = new URL(this.href); //get href
  var id = url.searchParams.get("id"); //get-id

  console.log(id) //204
    
  //Ajax
  $.ajax({
    url: 'your_url',
    data: {id: id},
    success: function(response) {
       //handle success
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      //handle error
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="more-link" href="https://barrera.pe/prueba/productos/barrera-3/?id=204">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to get the id is use [URLSearchParams()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and pass in the `search` property of the `<a>` element

```js
$(document).on('click', '.more-link', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const params = new URLSearchParams(this.search)
  console.log('id=', params.get('id'))
  // do ajax

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="more-link" href="https://barrera.pe/prueba/productos/barrera-3/?id=204">Click me</a>
```