# How can I turn a string into a Location object?

Tags: javascript, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a new Location object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213531/creating-a-new-location-object-in-javascript)

If the user inputs a string that is a URL, what's the easiest way to turn it into a [Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Location_object) (like `window.location`) so I can use methods and properties like `obj.hostname`?

Comment: `location.constructor()` === `TypeError: Illegal constructor`. Interpreter says no. You can always create an iframe, navigate to the url in the iframe then access the `location` object in the iframe. (bad idea)

Comment: @lwburk -- Yep, that's what I was trying to find with my 30 minutes of searching prior to posting this. >.>

Comment: Here is the perfect solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3213643/4477463

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know if you can create a Location object, but this article explains how to use an anchor tag for the same effect:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/parsing-urls-with-the-dom/