# How do I extract the base URL from a link-string with Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-parameters

How do I turn this:

```
http://bit.ly/Wn2Xdz
```

into this:

```
http://bit.ly/
```

Bear in mind that this would NOT be the current URL in the window, but a string. And the base URL might change (not all the time http://bit.ly).

Comment: Warning: If your website is ever hosted as a web application (under a path like domain.com/appname/) a simple string indexing answer will not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-root-domain-name-from-string

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I turn a string into a Location object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736595/how-can-i-turn-a-string-into-a-location-object)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736595/how-can-i-turn-a-string-into-a-location-object

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie "web applications that are not hosted at the domain root" what is this restriction? Question was not subjected to that kind of restriction right?

Comment: @Nishan Senevirathna: Question is not clear, but I already removed that comment as it may well be the simplest case only. Most answers will not cover the case of a web-app.

Answer (score 2):

you can use an anchor tag to parse it reliably:

```
var temp=document.createElement("a"); 
temp.href="http://bit.ly/Wn2Xdz"; 
alert(temp.origin+"/"); // shows: "http://bit.ly/"
```

Comment: Very clever solution. Unlike David's this includes the port too

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest, at its simplest:

```js
function hostnameFromURL(url) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  return a.protocol + '//' + a.hostname;
}

console.log(hostnameFromURL('http://bit.ly/Wn2Xdz')); // http://bit.ly
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a string manipulation thing, you can get the base url from given string as below

```
var url = "http://bit.ly/Wn2Xdz";
var temp = url.split("/");
var baseUrl = temp[0] + "//" + temp[2];//http://bit.ly
```

Comment: No this is not a simple one as string manipulation. Sometime you can get complex urls with port like 8080 or something else. So you can't rely on this.