# Add parameters to an URL from a <a href> just clicked

Tags: javascript

The scenario is a lot of html files with a lot more of links between them. When I call the first one of them (it would be the index), the link pass several parameters through the URL (we could call them preferences).

Now I want that, when clicking any of the several links of the page, those parameters would be added. So the problem would be similar to this other ( [How to add parameters to a URL that already contains other parameters and maybe an anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953944/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-url-that-already-contains-other-parameters-and-maybe)) but doing it just after clicking the link.

I know that one solution could be changing the ***onclick*** event on each link, but as there may be thousands of them, without a regular url format... I'm looking for a solution that could be on the script at the head; perhaps something relative to ***onbeforeunload*** event.

Anyway I couldn't find how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: So those parameters will move around with every request? Right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will append a string to anything containing an href-attribute when being clicked:

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    if(href) {
        location.href = href + "?q=stackoverflow";
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});​
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/E5Q7P/

Won't work in < IE9

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much.

BTW: I'm using it within an app for Android, including PhoneGap. When I tried it over Mozilla Firefox 10.0.7 (running on Linux) it didn't work.

Comment: I think srcElement is the problem. That's an IE-property, and the right property would be target. Seems that chrome implements srcElement as well for some reason. I've changed the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the onclick-attribute of each link, or using the onbeforeunload-event, I guess one way would be to attach a clickevent-listener to all anchor-elements when the page loads. The callback could then intercept the browsers default behavior to follow the link. You could then get the `src` attribute of the a-element that was just clicked, add the desired preferences to the URL and then send the user to the proper location (including preferences) by setting `window.location.href` to the proper URL.

There is a [great aricle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) on MDN about event-listeners, that I believe would be helpful to you. *Note specially the section about older versions of IE*

**A very crude example of what it could look like:**

```
function callback(e){
  // Get the src of the clicked a-element
  var src = this.src;
  // Add preferences to the url, this need 
  // improvement depending on your needs
  src += "?somesetting=foo";
  // Send user to the url with preferences
  window.location.href = src;
}

// Get all anchors on page
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

// Loop over the elements and attach listener
for(i=0 ; i < anchors.length ; i++){
  // Extend with support for older IE if needed
  anchors[i].addEventListener("click", callback, false});
}​
```