# Is it possible to append "#" to URL on clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My application is a single page application ,I am using links like shown below

```
<a class="list-group-item navigationlink" href="#" id="roletemplates-link" data-moduleid="2">Role Templates</a>
```

You can see that `href="#"`. On clicking that link I use ajax to load content to the page.

I want to append "**#**" to **URL** when I click that link **without reloading the page**. In many solutions I saw is like that the page will have to be reloaded if we want to append some values to variables.

**My Question:**

Is it possible to append the "**#**" to **URL** on clicking the link without reloading the page?

Comment: you can preevent the default and append the `#` using javascript, then update the `location/href`

Comment: What happens when you click with `href="#"`. I don't think it reloads, does it?

Comment: No.. But when I searched for " how to append data to URL " I found something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781345/add-parameters-to-an-url-from-a-a-href-just-clicked .. here the page will reload if I use this solution. So I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: I don't think it will reload with just `href="#"`. If it has a valid ID then for sure it won't reload (ex: `href="#roletemplates-link'`) and you will see the page getting scrolled to the element.

Comment: @Vega at present its not reloading. But "#" is not appending to URL.. I want to append "#" to URL

Comment: @RinoRaj `href="#"` will append a `#` when you click on it, but it won't if you have a `preventDefault` or a `return false` in your event handler.

Comment: @Vega I am using preventDefault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done via Javascript:

```
window.location.hash = "myfancynewhashtag";
```

Comment: can you add a fiddle or more details for reference ?

Comment: I wanted to but jsfiddle.net seems to prevent it

Comment: Put this in an html file and i promise you it works: http://pastebin.com/cYeSYA5L

Comment: This will work only if we give some value like you have given. I dont want to append value along with hash. only "#" not "#fancy" or somthing along with #

Comment: window.location.hash = " "; currently I am using like this.. since space cannot be seen ;).. Thanks.. your answer helped..

Answer (score 0):

Save your string '#' or anything in a hidden element and add it in the url directly by adding a function on onclick.

hope it works.

Comment: Can you show a demo for appending "#" without reloading the page?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script>
   function theFunction(){
   url="paste your content here";
   document.getElementById('mylink').href=   document.getElementById('hide')+url;
   }
   
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href=""  id="mylink" onclick="theFunction();">your Link</a>
 
<input type='hidden' name='hide' value='#'>

</body>
</html>

please check it and change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible that you can append # to the url.

Now the url can be same or different.

**In case of same url:**

It won't refresh the page at all.
Instead, it will search for the fragment identifier in the same and it will scroll to that portion of the page.

**In case of different url:**

It will reload the page and scroll to the portion of the page for which fragment identifier is mentioned after the #.

Hope that this answers your question.

Comment: Put this in an html file and i promise you it works: http://pastebin.com/cYeSYA5L

Comment: did it refresh the page for you? it did not for me and it won't for sure.It will append the #.I never said it won't add # to the url.What i have explained above is,what happens after adding # to the url.