# Adding params to url using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, url

I am a newbie to web development.

I have fixed initial url with params.

```
@url = http://localhost:3000/home/results?utf8=%E2%9C%93&what=&where=&commit=search&property_for=
```

Now, i want to add params to this url individually, like

```
@price = something
@bedrooms = something
```

final `url = @url + @price + @bedrooms`

How can i get this using javascript??
Can anyone provide reference code or link to understand

Comment: Is this for the current page that is loaded? Or are you trying to manipulate a target url to be used for AJAX or as an HRef?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953944/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-url-that-already-contains-other-parameters-and-maybe & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript

Comment: `var url = window.location.href +'&price='+price+'&bedrooms='+bedrooms;`

Comment: need to explain where javascript will get the url value shown from, and where the new parameters will come from within the page.. and what it will do with the revised url

Comment: No ajax, the parameter will come from within the page. By using window.locatio.href, the parameters getting added continously to the url, presently my url is working with  window.location += '&price_min=' + PropertyPriceFilter.min + '&price_max=' + PropertyPriceFilter.max;

Comment: I want to change above things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this function

```
function getURL(qs) {
   var href = document.location.href;
   if (href.indexOf('?') >= 0) href = href.substring(0, href.indexOf('?'));
   if (href.indexOf('#') >= 0) {
       href = href.substring(0, href.indexOf('#'));
   }
   if (qs) {
      document.location.href = href + (qs === true ? "" : ('?' + qs)) + document.location.hash;
}
else
    return href + document.location.hash;
    return 1;
}
```

you can pass true, if you dont want any querystring and pass "id=somevalue" to this function to get url along with querystring

Comment: Ya, This helped me understand how substr and indexOf are used