# Manipulate URL to start a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

is there a way to add some code to a link, so that it will automaticaly "load" some content into a "div".

For example: www.mysite123abcxyz.com - will show the page with project preview images. www.mysite123abcxyz.com/open - will show the page with the details of an project expanded.

The code for "opening" the details, which works so far:

```
<a  onclick="$('#openthis').slideDown(); $('#opentheother').slideUp(); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#detail').offset().top }, 800);"><img src="open.jpg"></img></a>
```

Comment: You can look at the value of `window.location.pathname` when the page loads.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953944/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-url-that-already-contains-other-parameters-and-maybe), it might help you. Try looking for similar questions to yours before asking next time.

Comment: server won't find that path and will throw a 404 error, should probably use url hash , then parse hash from `location.hash` on page load