# Given a URL as a string, how to extract just the domain and extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Given a string with URLs in the following formats:

```
https://www.cnn.com/
http://www.cnn.com/
http://www.cnn.com/2012/02/16/world/american-nicaragua-prison/index.html
http://edition.cnn.com/?hpt=ed_Intl
```

W JS/jQuery, how can I extract from the string just cnn.com for all of them? Top level domain plus extension?

Thanks

Comment: url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];

Comment: Why bother with regex. It's a Swiss army knife when all you need is a spoon.

Comment: @AnApprentice if you want subdomains, just use `location.host`. No need for regex at alla.

Answer (score 3):

```
​var loc = document.createElement('a');

loc.href = 'http://www.cnn.com/2012/02/16/world/index.html';

​window.alert(loc.hostname);​ // alerts "cnn.com"
```

Credits for the previous method:

[Creating a new Location object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213531/creating-a-new-location-object-in-javascript)

Comment: hence: `loc.hostname.split('.').slice(-2).join('.')`  but you're still gonna get screwed on the whole `.co.uk` type of domain...

Answer (score 1):

```
function domain(input){
    var matches,
        output = "",
        urls = /\w+:\/\/([\w|\.]+)/;

    matches = urls.exec(input);

    if(matches !== null){
        output = matches[1];
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var domain = location.host.split('.').slice(-2);
```

If you want it reassembled:

```
var domain = location.host.split('.').slice(-2).join('.');
```

But this won't work with co.uk or something. There's no hard nor fast rule for this, not even regex will determine that.

Comment: ... where `location.host` is the subject string

Comment: @satoshi `location.host` is the string property of the location object. It refers to the data between the '//' and the first '/' in your URL. It's in browsers back to IE6 and I believe even Netscape 4.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. `"http://www.cnn.com/2012/02/16/world/american-nicaragua-prison/index.html".split('.').slice(-2).join('.')` -> `"com/2012/02/16/world/american-nicaragua-prison/index.html"`

Comment: @ggg location is a browser object. Location.host is the server URL.  Try that in the chrome debugger or firebug, etc

Comment: What I'm saying is that the question author didn't ask to have this regex applied to the current page...

Comment: ah, you're right, my mistake! I somehow read that as `location.href`. By the way, this doesn't work with TLDs with dots in them (`co.uk` for example). @satoshi it could be used in conjunction with a trick like Xander proposes below (if it worked with dotted TLDs).

Answer (score 0):

Given that there are top-level domains with dots in them, for example "co.uk", there's no way to do this programatically unless you include a list of all of the TLDs with dots in them.

Answer (score -1):

```
// something.domain.com -> domain.com
function getDomain() {
  return window.location.hostname.replace(/([a-z]+.)/,"");
}
```

Comment: About your regular expression. A. you don't need to capture a group here. B. you're trying to match a . with a . that matches any other character too (except \n) So this should be: window.location.hostname.replace(/[a-z]+\./,"")