# Is possible to create instance of Location?

Tags: javascript

When I type `window` in console. console show that `window` is instance of `Window`. Is it possible to create new window object using `new Window()`. I tried it but it throwing error **TypeError: Illegal constructor**

My Question is related to `Location` object. can I create a new object using `Location`? 
I need it so that I can apply method available on `location` object to  my links.

I was trying to access Location object but no success.

I am using `Chrome console`.

Comment: Maybe there's another way that doesn't involve replicating an object. Can you tell us what method you needed?

Comment: Perhaps [creating-a-new-location-object-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213531/creating-a-new-location-object-in-javascript)

Comment: I want create Instance of location object. for example if I have link = example.com/?q=12&er=56#test; I want to create a location object. I so that I can manipulate the link above. I know I can use reg expression to manipulate link. I was curious to know if creation of instance of Location possible

Comment: @Shusl This simply *not* work as desired in this case. The Location object is *not* a general URI container, but is rather a special contract with the DOM and its navigation state. Consider asking the *real question* next time, like: "How can URIs be manipulated in JavaScript?"

Comment: it's a great shame that there isn't a JS mandatory URI class :(

Comment: I think it is not possible but you can have all location properties and method see SO thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213531/creating-a-new-location-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attempting to use `Location` to manipulate arbitrary URIs will *not* work as desired. The `Location` object/type is *not* a general URI container, but is rather a *special contract* with the DOM and its navigation state.

I found this [URI JavaScript type by webr3](https://github.com/webr3/URI) via google, YMMV:

> URI Type for javascript
>
> - Supports all kinds of URI (URL, URN, any scheme).
> - Relative URI Resolution
> - All classes extend the native String implementation.
> - Pure ECMA-262 implementation of URI spec (RFC-3986)
> - Works Client or Server side, (V8 / node.js compatible).

Answer (score 6):

Though the question is quite old, posting the answer anyway as using native HTML Web APIs is considered to be a good practice.

### Solution

- The HTML Web API [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL) allows us to create a URL object which has following properties in it.
- The typescript equivalent of this object looks like this -

```
interface URL {
    hash: string;
    host: string;
    hostname: string;
    href: string;
    readonly origin: string;
    password: string;
    pathname: string;
    port: string;
    protocol: string;
    search: string;
    username: string;
    readonly searchParams: URLSearchParams;
    toString(): string;
}
```

---

### Example

As an example,

```
var url = new URL('http://localhost:8081/route1/route2?q=test#route3/route4');
```

Gives you following object-

```
{
    hash: "#route3/route4"
    host: "localhost:8081"
    hostname: "localhost"
    href: "http://localhost:8081/route1/route2?q=test#route3/route4"
    origin: "http://localhost:8081"
    password: ""
    pathname: "/route1/route2"
    port: "8081"
    protocol: "http:"
    search: "?q=test"
    searchParams: URLSearchParams {}
    username: ""
}
```

---

### Compatibility Check

Check the [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL#Browser_compatibility) before using.

I hope this solution is useful for you.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't. A browser window has one instance of `window` and a window has one `location`.  Trying to create multiple instances of `window` or `window.location` would seem indicative of conceptual errors.

If I'm understanding what you want to do correctly, you should create an `anchor` element manipulate that with javascript:

```
var url = document.createElement('a');
url.href = "http://www.example.com/some/path?name=value#anchor";
var protocol = url.protocol;
var hash = url.hash;

alert('protocol: ' + protocol);
alert('hash: ' + hash);
```

Or, if you already have an anchor, you can use

```
var url = document.getElementById('myanchorid');
```

​

Comment: Good answer. So an anchor is effectively a Location of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the `window` object as a singleton. You cannot create a new instances of it. What would it mean? What would a new `Window` inside a `Window` be? It's similar with the `location` object of a `Window`. Each `Window` has a `location`, but no `Window` can be in two `location`s at once.

To modify the `location` of a `Window` use:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

To create a new (child) `Window` — a pop-up window — use the `open` method of the `window` object:

```
window.open('http://www.example.com');
```

To change the "location" of a link, modify the `href` attribute of the link. For example, to modify the HTML link:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="mylink">Visit Website</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

... use ...

```
document.getElementById("mylink").href = "http://www.yahoo.com";
```

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you can't create new `Location` objects yourself.

However, you can get pretty close. I built a small (~1kB) library that offers a custom `Location` function that works like you would expect the standard `Location` function to do:

### [ulocation](https://npmjs.com/package/ulocation)

With it you can create new location objects like this:

```
var x = new Location('https://joe:secret@example.com:8080/path?q=test#hash');
console.info(x.protocol);  // > 'https:'
console.info(x.hostname);  // > 'example.com'
console.info(x.port);      // > '8080'
console.info(x.pathname);  // > '/path'
console.info(x.search);    // > '?q=test'
console.info(x.hash);      // > '#hash'
```

The created location object works very similar to the `window.location` object or to anchors. If you set the `href`, all other fields update automatically:

```
x.href = 'http://www.example.org/wow'
console.info(x.protocol);  // > 'http:'
console.info(x.hostname);  // > 'www.example.org'
console.info(x.port);      // > ''
console.info(x.pathname);  // > '/wow'
console.info(x.search);    // > ''
console.info(x.hash);      // > ''
```

It even emits a `'change'` event whenever the URL changes that you can listen for:

```
x.on('change', function(){
  console.info(this.href);
})

x.href= 'https://stackoverflow.com'  // > 'https://stackoverflow.com'
```

It works on Node as well as on the browser but due to it's tiny size there is no separate web download; include it in your bundle using Webpack or Browserify.

Comment: Downvoters, care to comment? Lost 2 votes for no reason?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need your `Location` to do you can.
I used below code to create a `Location` for a unit test.

```
const windowLocation: Location = {
    host: 'localhost:4200',
    protocol: 'http:',
    ancestorOrigins: null,
    hash: null,
    href: null,
    hostname: null,
    origin: null,
    pathname: null,
    port: null,
    search: null,
    assign: null,
    reload: null,
    replace: null,
};
```