# Creating a Location object in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, location, typescript, href

I'm having trouble redirecting my app outside of Angular to the logout page.
I'm doing it by using `$window.location.href` but it's not working on FireFox.
So, There was a suggestion to use `$window.location` directly but since i'm writing in Typescript i need to create a new Location object rather then just assign my string to it...

I looked into lib.d.ts and i saw that location is declared as:

```
declare var Location: {
    prototype: Location;
    new(): Location;
}
```

so i adjust my code to:

```
var url: string = "http:\\\\host:port/blabla/logout";
var loc: Location = new Location();
loc.href = url;
this.$window.location = loc;
```

but got this error:

```
Error: Illegal constructor.
```

Any Idea how to create the Location object? Is it a good practice to do so?
Any other insights maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to assign a String directly and just make TypeScript go along with that, you can do

```
 window.location = <any>"http://host:port/blabla/logout";
```

Comment: Not sure if you can create a Location object at all. The DOM documentation just mentions that you can get it from `window.location` and `document.location` and that you can assign **a string** to it.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? I need a second location object, manipulate some properties and use the resulting url without changing the current location.

Answer (score 5):

It actually looks like you're [not supposed to build new `Location` objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680790/is-possible-to-create-instance-of-location). So I don't think there's a constructor available anywhere for this. Though you [can use anchors to build them for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213531/creating-a-new-location-object-in-javascript).

If you're trying to set a new location, you can go with setting `window.location.href` instead of `window.location` ([These two are equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-location-href-versus-location)).