# How to get the parts of a url using document.referrer?

Tags: javascript

I need to use `document.referrer` to get the previous URL I also need to be able to get the parts of the URL like:

```
window.location.protocol
window.location.host
window.location.pathname
```

but I can't figure out how to do it with `document.referrer`.  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a new Location object in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213531/creating-a-new-location-object-in-javascript)

Comment: `window.location` is an object, with handy dandy methods for grabbing the different bits. `document.referrer` on the other hand is a string, and so that'll need to be parsed manually.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create an a element with the referrer as its url.

a elements (with hrefs) can act like location objects

```
var a=document.createElement('a');
a.href=document.referrer;
alert([a.protocol,a.host,a.pathname].join('\n'));
a='';
```

Answer (score 6):

There's no equivalent to `window.location` with regards to `document.referrer` so your only option will be to break down the string itself. You could write a regex to do that or rely on a series of string splits:

```
var parts = document.referrer.split('://')[1].split('/');
var protocol = document.referrer.split('://')[0];
var host = parts[0];
var pathName = parts.slice(1).join('/');
```

Comment: `http://example.com/://foobar` is a valid URI accoriding to RFC 3986. Your `parts` could be missing something...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the convenience and can afford the weight, have a look at [URI.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/) or one of the suggested [URL parsers](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js#url-parsers). If you don't need anything fancy, [`<a>`s href decomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3213643/515124) will do the job just fine.